# Drag and drop onto a form (but not a WebBrowser control on the form)

Tags: .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a Windows Forms app (C#) that has a WebBrowser control (among a few other buttons and text boxes).  I want to be able to drop a file anywhere on the form.  The problem is that by default the WebBrowser will attempt to render any file dropped into its control; I don't want this as I have to perform some pre-processing on the file first.  The WebBrowser control provides a property named AllowWebBrowserDrop, which I set to false to disable this behavior.  However, the result is that I cannot drop anything on the WebBrowser control ("not allowed" feedback).  The WebBrowser control takes up the majority of the space, so it would be kind of lame if you had to drop the file in the slack space somewhere.  How can I enable dropping a file anywhere on my form without having the WebBrowser control try to render it?

I guess I should add that I have AllowDrop on my form set to true and have handlers for DragEnter and DragDrop.  I have AllowWebBrowserDrop on my WebBrowser set to false.  Everything else has the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing with the `WebBrowser`, you can handle the `Navigating` event, which fires before the browser navigates. Then determine if you want to handle the drop by checking the URL. For example:

```
private void browser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.IsFile)
    {
        // Prevent navigation
        e.Cancel = true;

        // Fire your other OnDrop code
    }
}
```

For this to work, you would want to leave `AllowWebBrowserDrop` set to `true`.

If this works for your business case, great; otherwise you're probably stuck handling window messages directly, as mentioned, which isn't much fun.

Comment: This is not quite exactly what I want, but for my purposes it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a transparent background colored `Panel` with a higher z-order than the WebBrowser above it and let the Panel handle the drop?

Comment: imo, this is likely to work for catching the drop event, but also likely to break the app as winforms only "fakes" the transparent backgrounds.  It's also likely to preclude other important events.

Comment: maybe overwrite the WndProc and forward _all_ events to the underlying WebBrowser, except for the Drop event could work.